# How to fix /var/lib/sudo writable by non-owner?

Tags: upgrade

Good afternoon.

My question is:
When I update the Linux repositories with the command `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, some error occurs:

```
sudo: /var/lib/sudo writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700
```

What do I need to do to avoid this error?